# Find Duplicate items in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database

1. `Clipboard` and
2. `ClipboardItemMapping`

Each clipboard may consists one or more item.

In `ClipboardItemMapping`, I have a column `ClipboardId` which is a foreign key which refers to the `Clipboard` table.

Now I want to get all those clipboards which are same i.e for clipboards to be same they should consists of same number of items and same items having same `itemGuid`.

I wrote the following query

```
INSERT INTO #SharedClipboardsList (ClipboardId, ClipboardGuid, ShareGuid)
    SELECT
        B.Id,
        A.ItemGuid,
        A.ShareGuid
    FROM 
        #SharedItems A
    INNER JOIN 
        Clipboard B ON A.ItemGuid = B.Guid
    WHERE 
        ItemType = 7;

    -- Calculate the item count for each clipboard in clipboardItemMapping
    INSERT INTO #ClipboardItemCounts (ClipboardId, itemCount)
        SELECT 
            A.clipboardId, COUNT(DISTINCT A.itemGuid) AS itemCount
        FROM 
            clipboardItemMapping A
        INNER JOIN  
            #SharedClipboardsList B ON A.clipboardId = B.ClipboardId
        WHERE 
            A.IsDeleted = 0
        GROUP BY 
            A.clipboardId

    -- Find combinations of clipboards that have at least one common item
    INSERT INTO #ClipboardItemsCombined (Clipboard1Id, Clipboard2Id)
        SELECT 
            A.clipboardId AS Clipboard1Id, B.clipboardId AS Clipboard2Id
        FROM 
            clipboardItemMapping A
        INNER JOIN 
            clipboardItemMapping B ON A.itemGuid = B.itemGuid
                                   AND A.clipboardId <> B.clipboardId
                                   AND A.clipboardId < B.clipboardId
                                   AND A.IsDeleted = 0
                                   AND B.IsDeleted = 0
        WHERE 
            A.clipboardId IN (SELECT ClipboardId FROM #SharedClipboardsList)
            AND B.ClipboardId IN (SELECT ClipboardId FROM #SharedClipboardsList)

    -- Filter out combinations of clipboards that have the same number of items
    INSERT INTO #ClipboardItemsCountMatch (Clipboard1Id, Clipboard2Id)
        SELECT 
            cc1.clipboardId AS Clipboard1Id, cc2.clipboardId AS Clipboard2Id
        FROM 
            #ClipboardItemCounts cc1
        INNER JOIN 
            #ClipboardItemCounts cc2 ON cc1.clipboardId <> cc2.clipboardId
                                     AND cc1.clipboardId < cc2.clipboardId 
                                     AND cc1.itemCount = cc2.itemCount;

    -- Find combinations of clipboards that have the exact same set of items
    INSERT INTO #ClipboardItemsMatch (Clipboard1Id, Clipboard2Id)
        SELECT cic.Clipboard1Id, cic.Clipboard2Id
        FROM #ClipboardItemsCombined cic
        GROUP BY cic.Clipboard1Id, cic.Clipboard2Id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT itemCount
                           FROM #ClipboardItemCounts
                           WHERE clipboardId = cic.Clipboard1Id)

    INSERT INTO #DuplicateClipboardsMap (Clipboard1Id, Clipboard2Id)
        SELECT DISTINCT
            c1.Id AS Clipboard1Id, 
            c2.Id AS Clipboard2Id
        FROM 
            clipboard c1
        INNER JOIN 
            clipboard c2 ON c1.Id <> c2.Id
                         AND c1.Id < c2.Id
        INNER JOIN 
            #ClipboardItemsCountMatch cm ON c1.Id = cm.Clipboard1Id 
                                         AND c2.Id = cm.Clipboard2Id
        INNER JOIN 
            #ClipboardItemsMatch ci ON c1.Id = ci.Clipboard1Id 
                                    AND c2.Id = ci.Clipboard2Id
        WHERE 
            c1.IsDeleted = 0 AND c2.IsDeleted = 0;


    SELECT * FROM #DuplicateClipboardsMap
```

In this query, I get duplicate clipboards but not in the way I want..

For e.g if there are same clipboards which ids are 801,809,815 and other same clipboard which ids are 105,118 then the output which I want is like:

```
|SameClipbords |
|{801,809,815} |
|{105,118}     |
```

But from the query I shared, I get this output in combination like:

```
|Clipboard1 | Clipboard2 |
|   801     |   802      |
|   802     |   809      |
|   801     |   809      |
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide proper sample data and expected results, as specified in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `STRING_AGG` to aggregate the items then count up how many lists you have per set of items.

Make sure to use a deterministic ordering for the aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(CAST(c.Id AS varchar(20), ',') AS DuplicateClipboards
FROM (
    SELECT
      c.Id,
      STRING_AGG(CAST(cim.itemGuid AS varchar(20), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cim.itemGuid) AS Items
    FROM clipboard c
    JOIN ClipboardItemMapping cim ON cim.Clipboard1Id = c.Id
    WHERE c.IsDeleted = 0
    GROUP BY
      c.Id
) c
GROUP BY
  c.Items
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Yes it worked after some modifications.. thanks!